Run two specific tests using testNamePattern in jest
I'm trying to run a set of tests using jest
I've tried :
-t=TC_66221_Test1|TC_67748_Test2
and
-t=^TC_66221_Test1$|^TC_67748_Test2$
But neither works.  Any idea as to how to run multiple tests within jest -t flag?
-t=TC_66221_Test1 works by itself as does -t=TC_67748_Test2

It seems --testNamePattern does not support array patterns yet. See https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/8683
